# Escape HTML on WP input

Tags: widgets

I am slightly stuck on creating a widget, it has an input (bit like the default text widget) but got an issue adding html into it.

My code is:

```
$instance['content'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['content'] ) ) ? esc_html( $new_instance['content'] ) : '';
```

This works partially as it let me saves the HTML (an iframe) but displays it as code in the frontend, I need it to convert the iframe code to a working video.

I have also tried:

```
$instance['content'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['content'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['content'] ) : '';
```

but it won't let me save the iframe content (it clears the box).

Which function do I need to use so my widget behaves the same as the default text widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default text widget - [`WP_Widget_Text`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L476) - can be found in `wp-includes/default-widgets.php`. The input is handled like this:

- `stripslashes( wp_filter_post_kses( addslashes( $text ) ) );` for the text;

I assume this should work likewise for your custom widget. Additionally there is:

- `wpautop( $text )` on the output, if the filter is set to do that;

But optimally you're taking a look at the source yourself.

Additionally the codex articles:

- [Validating Sanitizing and Escaping User Data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data); and
- [Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)

give you an good overview about sanitizing, escaping and validating possibilities with WP.

Comment: My pleasure. Ok, but actually `wpautop()` shouldn't be necessary, but this depends on the santizing/escaping function(s) used. @GarethGillman